# Setting up Xamarin Studio Version Control with TFS + git

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, xamarin-studio

I am setting up **Xamarin** with **Team Foundation Service + git** to develop iOS apps. I have tried many different settings trying to set up my TFS + git integration on our MAC with no avail. I keep getting exceptions of either `not authorized` or `failed to fetch`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am going to list all steps I took to be as complete as possible.

1. First of all, I created a hosted TFS account and added a `New Team Project + Git`
2. I then had to create alternative login credentials since you cannot have an `@` symbol in your login info. 
       To set up alternate creds in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), click on your name on the top right -> My Profile -> Credentials
3. After enabling the alternative credentials open Xamarin Studio. In my case I had a solution that I wanted to add so I had my solution file open as well.
4. Under the `Version Control` menu item select `Publish` (Only available with solution file open)
5. Select the `Registered Repositiories` tab and select `Add`
6. Enter an appropriate name. Select `https` protocol.
7. Enter your hosted TFS URL ie. `xxx.visualstudio.com`.
8. For port, enter `443`.
9. The path will be: `/DefaultCollection/_git/` + project name (exactly as you typed it including spaces)
10. User will be the alternative username you created in step 2. Click `OK` on both open windows.
11. You will be prompted to confirm publishing. Select `OK`.
12. You will then be prompted for your password. Enter you alternative password you created in step 2. If you accidentally enter the wrong password here, you must delete the entry from your key chain. Instructions can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH7293)

Your **TFS + git integration with Xamarin Studio** should be complete! If you have any other issues I will try my best to help with them.

Comment: you can use @ symbol in your login by creating a personal access token as in the url which you provided. I wasn't able to connect with username(my email)+password but i was able to connect with username(my email)+ access token.

Comment: I am using a local TFS with TFS Users, so no need for alternative credentials.
But Im not able to get past this 401 Error. It worked all fine when i did a publish. After that not able to do push changes at all. 
Also trying to checkout the project on another machine using Xamarin Studio and its giving the same error.
Similar to : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57087/local-tfs-git-xamarin-studio-401-unauthorized 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: I had to enable basic authentication on IIS in order for this to work.  I don't think this is installed / enabled by default for on premises TFS.  We are using only SSL for TFS so I didn't see the harm in enabling this for testing.  Xamarin studio was able to connect to GIT repo once enabled.

Comment: Link from step 2 does not exist anymore.

Comment: @K232, I have added the instructions in line and removed the link. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

In step 12. on Windows 8 and you entered the wrong password you will have to fix it in Credential Manager.

In windows 8

In Control Panel,
Open Credential Manager,
On the top of the page you have two options, select "Windows Credentials".
Under "Generic Credentials" look for a record for "your.visualstudio.com" click to expand and select remove.
Now if you publish from Xamarin Studio you will be prompted for your password again.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems connecting to my visualstudio.com repository even when following these instructions. What I did was to use XCode to checkout (or clone) the repository. I then opened my solution in Xamarin and it picked up the repository info just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com), which is a command line tool. But once you clone the repository you are able to use all the functionality like blame, revert, commit. It works with the new OSX version of Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found to connect Xamarin/Visual Studio Mac to TFS:

[Xamarin DevOps with VSTS - Getting Started](http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/xamarin-dev-ops-with-vsts-getting-started/)