# Connect to TFS Git from Xamarin Studio (non-hosted, locally installed TFS 2013)

Tags: git, tfs, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498404/setting-up-xamarin-studio-version-control-with-tfs-git) [instructions](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.it/2013/02/how-to-use-team-foundation-service-with.html) on how to connect to TFS Git from Xamarin Studio if you're using the Team Foundation Service.

We have locally installed TFS 2013 which also has Git support, but Xamarin Studio is unable to connect to it with the following error:
`Version control operation failed: authentication not supported`.

Is there a way to work it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable HTTP basic authentication in TFS.

Comment: thanks, it works! One more thing, is that username should be entered in "domain\user" format

Comment: I get a secure connection cannot be established

Comment: I now also quite often do pulls/pushes via console `git` and commits/reverts via Xamarin Studio. That also works.

Comment: Horrifying.  For the love of god, if you're going to do this, at least turn on SSL and turn off HTTP as well.

Answer (score 1):

I made the edits suggested in the accepted answer and received the same secure connection error message mentioned in the above comments.  It appears a bug in this functionality was discovered in May of this year and, according to the Bugzilla entry, the fix has not yet been released.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19616

Instead of using Git to access our TFS repository, we use Eclipse along with the Team Explorer Everywhere Plugin.  Xamarin provides instructions on how to configure this solution.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ad a secondary name on you TFS user account. In TFS online, click on your name, My Profile. Then click the credentials tab. In here you can put your secondary name.
Now remove the previous credential from keychain, and try again.

Comment: thanks, but the question was explicitly about non-cloud TFS (not TFS online or TFS Service)